# Resources not referencing the same related resource

Tags: jsdata, js-data-angular

I've defined two resources - **Foo** and **Bar** - where **Foo** contains one **Bar**. However, when inserting some basic data in this format, if multiple **Foo**'s reference the same **Bar**, then only the most recently loaded **Foo** is given a reference to it. Previous **Foo**'s have no **Bar** (it is undefined.)

The resources are defined like so:

```
DS.defineResource({
    name: 'Foo',
    relations: {
        hasOne: {
            Bar: {
                foreignKey: 'fooId',
                localField: 'bar'
            }
        }
    }
});

DS.defineResource({
    name: 'Bar',
    relations: {
        belongsTo: {
            Foo: {
                localField: "foo",
                localKey: "fooId"
            }
        }
    }
});
```

And I am injecting the following test data:

```
var foosJson = [
    {
        id: 1,
        bar: {
            id: 100
        }
    }, {
        id: 2,
        bar: {
            id: 100
        }
    }, {
        id: 3,
        bar: {
            id: 200
        }
    }
];
```

Why does the first Foo not have a reference to the same Bar as the second Foo?

Fiddle with Jasmine tests here: http://jsfiddle.net/dimmreaper/c0o1kqd0/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not working because it looks like you're actually trying for a many-to-many relationship. "bar belongsTo foo" means that any individual bar belongs to (at most) exactly *one* foo, but here you're trying to make bar #100 belong to both foo #1 and foo #2, which isn't a belongsTo relationship.

Since each bar doesn't actually have the field that `localKey` expects (`fooId`), JSData is trying to infer the field for you, and due to how the iteration works, JSData infers that bar #100 belongsTo foo #2, so `foo1.bar` is going to be `undefined`.

Comment: Thanks! So, is there a way to configure a many-to-many relationship with the given json example?